# how to force bison to immediate compilation

Tags: bison

I'd like to compose a "classic" BASIC syntax mixed with a bit more free format, e.g.:

```
a=5:b=6:c=a+b           // writing several instructrions into a single line
                // using colon as separator
                // but eliminating mandatory terminals (like ';' in c)

while (x < 3 ) {        // condition has mandatory parentheses around, but
x=x+1:y=y+2         // body of 'while' may also have multi-statements line(s)
z=y+y               // and may have several lines as well
}
```

To realise it I set up the following rules. My flex does its duty, correctly eliminates unnecessary linefeeds, etc:

```
^[ \t\r\n]*\n           /*ignore empty line */
\/\/.*\n ;          /* skip comment */
[ \t\r\n]+ ;            /* ignore whitespace */
\{[ \t\r\n]*\} ;        return EMPTY;
\{[ \t\r\n]* ;          return '{';
\}[ \t\r\n]* ;          return '}';
```

Unfortunately a stmt followed by a colon does not force the compiler to do **immediate** compilation.
However it is often expected in the second half of the line that proceeding code being compiled.
Here is the structure of my bison file.

```
%type <nPtr> stmt stmt_list expr

%%
line:
    line stmt_list ':' {        // <-- this is my problem
        ex($2); freeNode($2);
        }
    | line stmt_list '\n' {
        ex($2); freeNode($2);
        }
    | /* NULL */
    ;

stmt:   VARIABLE '=' expr       { $$ = opr('=', 2, $3, id($1)); }
    | PORT '=' expr         { $$ = opr('=', 2, $3, id($1)); }
    | .... etc.
    | WHILE '(' expr ')' EMPTY  { $$ = opr(WHILE, 1, $3); }
    | WHILE '(' expr ')' stmt_list  { $$ = opr(WHILE, 2, $3, $5); }
    ;

stmt_list:
    stmt                { $$ = $1; }
    | '{' stmt_list '}'     { $$ = $2; }
    | '{' error '}'         { errorflag=1; }
    | error  '\n'           { errorflag=1; }
    ;

expr:
    INTEGER             { $$ = con($1); }
    | VARIABLE          { $$ = id($1); }
    | .... etc.
    | '(' expr ')'          { $$ = $2; }
    ;
```

How can I modify it to make the expected behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "immediate compilation"?  What is the expected behavior and what is happening instead?  Try to include a [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to remember about bison actions is that they are executed when the right-hand side has been fully parsed.

Consider the two simple recursive productions:

```
a: N a | %empty ;
```

and

```
a: a N | %empty ;
```

Let's apply them to the input:

```
N1 N2 N3
```

With the right-recursive case (the first one), the productions will be as follows (the subscripts are just for clarity):

`a0 → N1 a1
a1 → N2 a2
a2 → N3 a3
a3 → ε`

and the parse tree is:

`a0`      
 `+-----+-----+` 
 `|           |` 
 `|       a1`    
 `|   +---+---+` 
 `|   |       |` 
 `|   |     a2`  
 `|   |   +-+-+` 
 `|   |   |   |` 
 `|   |   |   a3`
 `|   |   |   |` 
 `N1  N2  N3  ε`

while the left-recursive one (the second one), produces:

`a0 → a1 N3
a1 → a2 N2
a2 → a3 N1
a3 → ε`

and the parse tree is:

`a0`     
 `+-----+-----+`
 `|           |`
     `a1      |`
 `+---+---+   |`
 `|       |   |`
   `a2    |   |`
 `+-+-+   |   |`
 `|   |   |   |`
 `a3  |   |   |`
 `|   |   |   |`
 `ε   N1  N2  N3`

The important thing to observe is that in the right-recursive case, all the productions include the entire input string, and the parser actions therefore take place *right to left*. In the left-recursive case, in contrast, the productions successively produce prefixes of the string, and the parser actions take place *left to right*.

In conclusion, if you want your actions to occur left to right, use left recursion.

Answer (score 2):

I see a number of severe problems with your example

- Your grammar uses `'\n'` (newline) tokens, but your lexer ignores newlines and will never return them, so the rules involving newlines can never be reduced
- Your example says that multiple statement lines (with colons) can appear in `WHILE` bodies, but your grammar does not allow for such

because of these, the parser can't even parse the second line of your input correctly, let alone get into the loops.